# trying to run selenium in ruby "127.0.0.1" port 9514 (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This is my file

> require 'selenium-webdriver'
>
> driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for:chrome

I have the chrome selenium driver file in my path `c:\windows\system32\chromedriver.exe`  I got the file from `https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=73.0.3683.20/`

This kind of thing has worked for me before.

```
C:\blah>ruby aaa.rb
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:78:in `stop': undefined method `poll_for_exit' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:67:in `block in start'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/platform.rb:141:in `block in exit_hook'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_lock.rb:61:in `initialize': The requested address is not valid in its context. - bind(2
) for "127.0.0.1" port 9514 (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_lock.rb:61:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_lock.rb:61:in `can_lock?'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_lock.rb:50:in `lock'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_lock.rb:36:in `locked'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:69:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/driver.rb:44:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:44:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:44:in `for'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:86:in `for'
        from aaa.rb:4:in `<main>'

C:\blah>
```

I thought maybe the file is for some reason suddenly requiring to be written to, and that being located in `c:\windows\system32` was limiting it,  so I moved it to c:\abc and added that to the path, but still same error.

The error mentions port 9514.  I have nothing listening on port 9514

> C:\Users\user>netstat -aon | grep 9514
>
> C:\Users\user>

I'm also able to start a server on port 9514 and make something listen on it (tested with `nc -l 9514`  and `netstat -aon | grep 9514`) so there's no problem for a server to listen on port 9514.

doing ruby -d aaa.rb

```
C:\rubytest\garybrown>ruby -d aaa.rb
Exception `LoadError' at C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems.rb:1355 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/ruby
aaa.rb:4: warning: assigned but unused variable - driver
Exception `LoadError' at C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55 - cannot load such file -- selenium-webdriver
Exception `LoadError' at C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25-x64-mingw32/lib/ffi/library.rb:259 - LoadError
Exception `LoadError' at C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25-x64-mingw32/lib/ffi/library.rb:259 - LoadError
Using Ext extension for JSON.
Exception `Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL' at C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_lock.rb:61 - The requested address is not valid in
its context. - bind(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 9514
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:136: warning: instance variable @process not initialized
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:78: warning: instance variable @process not initialized
Exception `NoMethodError' at C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:78 - undefined method `poll_for_exit' for nil:NilClass

C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:136: warning: instance variable @process not initialized
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:78:in `stop': undefined method `poll_for_exit' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:67:in `block in start'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/platform.rb:141:in `block in exit_hook'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_lock.rb:61:in `initialize': The requested address is not valid in its context. - bind(2
) for "127.0.0.1" port 9514 (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_lock.rb:61:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_lock.rb:61:in `can_lock?'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_lock.rb:50:in `lock'
```

I tried `gem install selenium-webdriver` but still same issue

I have Chrome version 72 and according to http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads  the compatible version is  ChromeDriver 2.46 or ChromeDriver 72.0.3626.69 but both give the same error.

I tried making a Gemfile with

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'selenium-webdriver'
```

and doing `bundle install`

but still `ruby aaa.rb` gives the same error

Comment: I might try resetting tcp/ip stack or something 'cos I notice I Ican't ping 127.0.0.1..  nc was binding to 0.0.0.0 I hadn't tested binding to 127.0.0.1 .. will look into this

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned in comment

> I might try resetting tcp/ip stack or something 'cos I notice I Ican't
>   ping 127.0.0.1.. nc was binding to 0.0.0.0 I hadn't tested binding to
>   127.0.0.1 .. will look into this

Certainly not being able to ping 127.0.0.1 was a great lead.. I tried resetting the tcp/ip stack as mentioned here https://superuser.com/questions/29720/general-failure-when-pinging-to-127-0-0-1

Running the command `netsh int ip reset` then restarting, I found I could then ping 127.0.0.1  and that I no longer got that error.